# Create an AWS IAM policy that only allows resources to be created within a certain resource group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In my AWS account we have 3 different applications, A, B, C.

I want to create an IAM policy for the B team that allows them to create new EC2 instances, but limit it to be tagged within the B resource group, or some other constraint that can definitively associate that new instance with the B group. Is that possible?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is absolutely possible with IAM, using the [`Condition`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition) element.  The Condition element lets you build expressions in which you can use Boolean operators to match against a condition, which in your case will be a resource with a specific tag.

For example, if you tag all the application B resources with "GroupB", the below IAM policy will restrict a user to being able to Start, Stop, and Reboot **only** EC2 resources that have that tag:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",      
        "ec2:RebootInstances"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/GroupB":"true"
        }
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:your_region:your_account_ID:instance/*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can find more information on Resource Groups on the AWS ["What Are Resource Groups"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/managing-resource-groups.html#modifying-resources-in-a-group) page.

Comment: will it allow them to CREATE new instances as long as they are tagged GroupB as well?

Comment: Tags are assigned (initially) when you create an instance so I don't think that's possible.  You could try creating a custom AMI and then restrict particular groups to only be able to start AMIs with a particular AMI ID (ami-xxxxxxxx).